# Popup doesn't close when ClickMode=Press

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, popup, togglebutton

I have a `ToggleButton` that shows a `Popup`. The `Popup` is shown and should close automatically because `StaysOpen="False"`. But the `ClickMode="Press"` breaks the popup because the mouse isn't captured properly by the `Popup`.

Can this be solved in XAML or code without using `ClickMode="Release"`?

The following code reproduces the issue:

```html
<ToggleButton x:Name="toggleButton"
              ClickMode="Press"
              Content="Toggle Popup" />
<Popup Width="{Binding ElementName=toggleButton, Path=ActualWidth}"
       IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=toggleButton}"
       Placement="Bottom"
       PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=toggleButton}"
       StaysOpen="False">
    <Button>Content</Button>
</Popup>
```

I found the solution:

On the `ToggleButton` add a `LostMouseCapture` event handler and (if `Mouse.Captured == null`) call `Mouse.Capture(inputElement, CaptureMode.SubTree)`. Where `inputElement` is the first logical child from the `Popup` that implements `IInputElement`.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Popup and Togglebutton interaction in wpf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821709/popup-and-togglebutton-interaction-in-wpf)

Comment: Why do you need this (kind of weird) setup and why does `ClickMode` have to be `Release`?

Comment: ClickMode should be Press but it breaks

Comment: Yes, you mentioned that - but why? What are you trying to achieve? What does this do? What's the intended behavior from start to finish?

Comment: The duplicates don't solve the capturing issue.

Comment: @ManfredRadlwimmer It's similar behavior as in combobox.Popup is shown when pressed not when released.