# How can I close a popup in WPF from inside its user control

Tags: wpf, xaml, popup

I have implemented a toggle button with a popup similar to what is described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5821709/popup-and-togglebutton-interaction-in-wpf).  My popup displays a user control that is basically a custom menu with several images/buttons on it.  Here is the code for my toggle button:

```
<ToggleButton x:Name="btnMenu" Background="Transparent" HorizontalAlignment="Right">
   <StackPanel>
      <Image Width="60" Height="60" Margin="10,0,10,0" Source="{StaticResource icon-menu}"/>
      <Popup StaysOpen="False" IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=btnMenu}" Placement="Bottom">
         <controls:Menu/>
      </Popup>
   </StackPanel>
</ToggleButton>
```

Everything works fine, except that when I click on a button (which is bound to a command) in my user control, I would like the popup to disappear.  Is there a way, through xaml, that I can close the parent popup when a button on the user control is pressed?

I did manage to find solutions on [codeproject](https://www.codeproject.com/Questions/1211019/Close-popup-in-user-control-WPF) which would most likely solve the problem, and I also found various solutions on StackOverflow where all the xaml was inside the popup instead of a separate user control. I wanted to see if there was another preferred method (hopefully xaml based) that could solve this particular problem, and still let me keep my menu in a separate user control.