# WPF popup staysopen=false still keep the popup open while clicking outside

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml

my problem here is I made a listbox inside the popup, and set the popup's staysopen=false. But each time popup box pops, I have to click something inside the popup(like select an element in listbox), then click outside the popup, and it will close automatically. If I don't click anything, and even if I click other elements outside the popup, the popup stays on. I need the popup closes without needing me to click any element inside it. What can I do? Here is the code, there are some other style link to this code but just some color style.

My control is when user click the textbox on the top of the popup box, the listbox pops. If user does nothing and click any place outside this element, the popup box closes. Thanks.

I can use the following code to get it done in silverlight. But seems like in wpf, it is not working anymore.

`popupAncestor = FindHighestAncestor(this.ListBoxPopup);
            if (popupAncestor == null)
            {
                return;
            }
            popupAncestor.AddHandler(System.Windows.Controls.Primitives.Popup.MouseLeftButtonDownEvent, (MouseButtonEventHandler)ClosePopup, true);`

```
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid" Margin="0" VerticalAlignment="Center">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="20"></RowDefinition>
        <RowDefinition Height="auto"></RowDefinition>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Grid Margin="1,1,1,0" x:Name="TopBar"  Visibility="Visible"  Grid.Row="0" Height="20" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Background="{StaticResource COL_BTN_LIGHT}">
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"></ColumnDefinition>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="19"></ColumnDefinition>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBox x:Name="TextBoxSearchItem"  x:FieldModifier="private" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Grid.Column="0" VerticalAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0,0,0,0" Background="Transparent" TextChanged="TextBoxSearchItem_TextChanged"></TextBox>
        <ToggleButton x:Name="DropDownArrorButton" Grid.Column="1" Style="{StaticResource ComboBoxReadonlyToggleButton}"></ToggleButton>
        <!--<TextBlock HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="Search" Grid.ColumnSpan="2" TextBlock.FontStyle="Italic" Opacity="0.4" VerticalAlignment="Center"/>-->
    </Grid>
    <Grid Grid.Row="1" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" x:Name="PopupGrid"  Margin="0,1,0,0" >
        <Popup x:Name="ListBoxPopup" StaysOpen="False" x:FieldModifier="private"  IsOpen="{Binding ElementName=DropDownArrorButton, Path=IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay}" 
               AllowsTransparency="true" Margin="0" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" Placement="Bottom" 
               PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=TopBar}"  Opened="OnPopupOpened" Closed="OnPopupClosed"
               HorizontalOffset="{Binding ElementName=PopupGrid, Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}"
                 VerticalOffset="{Binding ElementName=PopupGrid, Path=Value, Mode=TwoWay}">
            <ListBox x:Name="ListBoxContainer" Width="{Binding ElementName=MainGrid, Path=ActualWidth}" 
                     HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" SelectionMode="Single"  Height="200"  Margin="0" 
                     SelectionChanged="ListBoxContainer_SelectionChanged"
                     MouseDoubleClick="ListBoxContainer_MouseDoubleClick">
                <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                    <DataTemplate>
                        <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch">
                            <Border BorderBrush="{Binding SearchedBackColor}" BorderThickness="{Binding Indicator}" Width="{Binding ElementName=MainGrid, Path=ActualWidth}">
                                <TextBlock x:Name="ContentText" Text="{Binding Name}" Margin="1,0,0,0"/>
                            </Border>                               
                        </Grid>
                    </DataTemplate>
                </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
            </ListBox>
        </Popup>                
        <Border x:Name="listBorder" BorderBrush="{StaticResource COL_BTN}" BorderThickness="0,1,0,0" ></Border>     
    </Grid>                 
</Grid>
```

Comment: have you tried automatically giving focus to something in the popup when it displays?

Comment: What control is hosting the popup and how does it get shown?

Comment: 1 - Post your XAML. 2 - Post your code.

Comment: I am using grid to host the popup, and above the grid, there is a textbox, just like a editable combobox. But I need more flexible control, so I did not use combobox.

Comment: Why? You can independently control the contents of the selected item and item list. The item list could be a 2x5 grid of checkboxes if you wanted.

Comment: Take a look at: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687463/wpf-popup-staysopen-false-still-keep-the-popup-open-while-clicking-outside

Answer (score 0):

You should create a dependency property in your view model or control for "IsPopupOpen" as shown below to manage state of the popup. Then you can bind both the ToggleButton "IsChecked" and popup "IsOpen" to that DP.

Also on your ToggleButton, set "Focusable=false" and "IsThreeState=false"

```
    public bool IsDropDownOpen
    {
     get { return (bool)GetValue(IsDropDownOpenProperty); }
     set { SetValue(IsDropDownOpenProperty, value); }
    }        

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsDropDownOpenProperty =
          DependencyProperty.Register("IsDropDownOpen", typeof(bool), typeof(Window), new UIPropertyMetadata(false));
```

Good luck!

Comment: I made the usercontrol inheriting the combobox and restyle the combobox and get it done, thanks guys.

Comment: Hi Lance, glad to hear you figured out a way around your issue. Inheriting from ComboBox has a lot of other implications that wouldn't make it a proper answer to your initial question. If possible, please judge whether one of the responses solves the original question and then mark it as correct.