# Popup with usercontrol as content+ autocloses on mouse click

Tags: c#, wpf, popup

I have a WPF usercontrol comprising of Calender + timepicker.
I intend to use this usercontrol within a popup and show the popup on a textbox focus.
My problem is I am able to show the popup correctly, but the moment the user selects a date in the calendar, the popup closes automatically.

The user basically has no options to scroll through the years/months/days before selecting a specific date. How do I keep the popup open till the textbox loses focus.

I have tried StaysOpen + isOpen, but both of them are not working.

thanks

I am posting a part of XAML which I have within a control template for a texbox

```
<Popup x:Name="DatePickerPopup" IsOpen="False"
                           Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                           Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Calendar/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Popup>
```

after having bool Dependency property in my custom control

```
<Popup x:Name="DatePickerPopup" IsOpen="{Binding IsPopupOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                           Width="{Binding ActualWidth, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                           Height="{TemplateBinding Height}">
                        <Grid>
                            <Calendar/>
                        </Grid>
                    </Popup>
```

Comment: do you have some example code you are using?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687463/wpf-popup-staysopen-false-still-keep-the-popup-open-while-clicking-outside

You can also add a Coerce callback in case the value would be influenced by the IsOpen property of the Popup.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have similar functionality in several `Popup` controls and `IsOpen` works just perfectly for me... I'm not sure what you're doing with it. I bind it to a `bool` property and just change this property value when I want it to open or close:

```
<Popup Name="SuggestionsPopup" IsOpen="{Binding IsPopupOpen, RelativeSource={
    RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Controls:
    AutoCompleteTextBox}}}" StaysOpen="False" MaxHeight="{Binding MaxPopupHeight, 
    RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type Controls:
    AutoCompleteTextBox}}}" AllowsTransparency="True">
```

Comment: @eranotzap, why would you format this code so that it cannot all be seen without scrolling? Please do not edit other peoples posts just because the formatting is not in *your* preferred style. This is *my* code and I want to display it so that no one needs to scroll to see it.

Comment: I tried doing this .. but still facing the same issue.. I have appended the sample code

Comment: The moment I select an entry within the calender, the IsPopupOpen callback gets triggered, with args.NewValue being false.. this once again closes the popup..

Comment: I suppose that what I am saying with my post is that using the `Popup` control and the `IsOpen` property works fine. Therefore, it is *your* code that is closing it, not the `Popup`s internal code. You just need to find that part.

Comment: @Sheridan yes please, the part which is triggering the close, is the selection of dates within the calendar control. Is there something which I could do to evade this?

Comment: The way that I get around problems like this is by testing... take that `Calendar` out of the `Popup` control (temporarily) and test whether you can get the `Popup` to stay open. If you can, then try adding a different control inside... does that work? If so, what's the difference between that control and the `Calendar`? Can you put it in a `Grid` or `StackPanel`? Does that make any difference? Are you handling any `Calendar` events? Does the `Popup` still close if you comment out your handlers? Etc, etc, etc.

Answer (score 0):

I have fixed this problem.
I infact downloaded the source code for WPF toolkit, available at http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/.

They had a datetimepicker control which had the same scenario.

I added a toggle button and then bound the IsOpen property of Popup to the IsChecked property of Toggle button. Things worked fine for me. Here is the demo code.

```
<ToggleButton Margin="1" x:Name="_calenderButton"
                        IsChecked="{Binding IsOpen, RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}}"
                        IsEnabled="{Binding IsDateTimePickerReadOnlyCallback, 
                        RelativeSource={RelativeSource TemplatedParent}, Converter={StaticResource invertBoolConverter}}"
                        Grid.Column="1">
                        <Image Height="20" Width="20" Source="pack://application:,,,/Common;component/Images/calender2.jpg"/>
                    </ToggleButton>


<Popup x:Name="PART_Popup" IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, ElementName=_calenderButton}" StaysOpen="False">
                        <Border BorderThickness="1" Padding="3" Background="{StaticResource PopupBackgroundBrush}" 
                                BorderBrush="{StaticResource PopupDarkBorderBrush}">
                            <StackPanel>
                                <Calendar x:Name="PART_Calender" BorderThickness="0"/>
                                <commonControls:TimePicker x:Name="PART_TimePicker"
                                                           />
                            </StackPanel>
                        </Border>
                    </Popup>
```

Cheers