# How to close popup window when dialog box open in wpf?

Tags: wpf

I am opening one popup during the run time after that i will open the dialog box using window key down event now my previous popup still shows? how to close the previous pop up window ?
Can any one helps ?

---

Hi thanks for your words,

but unfortunately i am not using WPF popup. we have our own control. When we open Microsoft dialog window our popup window still opens. If i open dialog by pressing Window+E key mu pop up is closing as we expected but i open dialog throw Window_KeyDown event , in this case my popup does not close? Please help me?

Comment: Some code would help.  Can you show us the code that opens the window the first time & on the key down event?

Comment: [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13687463/wpf-popup-staysopen-false-still-keep-the-popup-open-while-clicking-outside) might help a little. would also like to see code.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to declare a `bool` property to data bind to the [`Popup.IsOpen` Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.primitives.popup.isopen%28v=vs.110%29.aspx):

```
<Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsPopupOpen}">
    <TextBlock Text="I'm a Popup" />
</Popup>
```

Then you can open and/or close it from your code behind or view model:

```
// Open Popup
IsPopupOpen = true;
// Close Popup
IsPopupOpen = false;
```

Answer (score 1):

assuming you are talking about the WPF popup control, this solution may work for you

```
<Popup StaysOpen="false" />
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know that one. I'm used to @Sheridan's approach. Hopefully that works for the OP.