# How to display Popup with StaysOpen=false when the user click RibbonButton

Tags: wpf, xaml, button, popup, ribbon

To reproduce, please download and install [Microsoft Ribbon for WPF](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=11877).

I need to display **Popup** when the user clicks **RibbonButton**. Also, I need to hide **Popup** when the user click anywhere but the **Popup**, so I will have to set `StaysOpen` property to **false**.

I have created a new WPF Ribbon Application. After that, I have changed default MainWindow.xaml implementation like this:

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ribbon:Ribbon x:Name="Ribbon">
        <ribbon:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
            <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu SmallImageSource="Images\SmallIcon.png">
                <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Hello _Ribbon"
                                                  x:Name="MenuItem1"
                                                  ImageSource="Images\LargeIcon.png"/>
            </ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu>
        </ribbon:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
        <ribbon:RibbonTab x:Name="HomeTab" 
                          Header="Home">
            <ribbon:RibbonGroup x:Name="Group1" 
                                Header="Group1">
                <ribbon:RibbonButton x:Name="Button1"
                                     LargeImageSource="Images\LargeIcon.png"
                                     Label="Button1"
                                     Click="Button1_Click"/>
                <Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=Button1}"
                       StaysOpen="False"
                       Name="p">
                    <TextBlock Background="Green" Text="Popup Text" />
                </Popup>

                <Button Click="Button1_Click" Content="Open popup" />

            </ribbon:RibbonGroup>

        </ribbon:RibbonTab>
    </ribbon:Ribbon> 

</Grid>
```

and MainWindow.xaml.cs:

```
public partial class MainWindow : RibbonWindow
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        // Insert code required on object creation below this point.
        p.Opened += new EventHandler(p_Opened);
        p.Closed += new EventHandler(p_Closed);
    }

    void p_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("closed");
    }

    void p_Opened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        System.Diagnostics.Debug.Print("opened");
    }

    private void Button1_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        p.IsOpen = true;
    }
}
```

When I start the application, clicking on the ordinary **Button**, I can see the **Popup**. But when I click on the **RibbonButton**, I couldn't see it anymore. I can see in the `Output` window that the `Opened` event of the **Popup** is raised, but then immediatly `Closed` event of the **Popup** is raised.

**Q:** How to display Popup with StaysOpen=false when the user click RibbonButton

Answer (score 4):

Checking the question posted [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333905/wpf-popup-hiding-problem) (I did try it myself as well), one half of the solution is to use the `ClickMode="Press"` property on the `RibbonButton` to make the popup open. This creates another problem since it seems to stop all future `RibbonButton.Click` events from triggering and I have not managed to find what is preventing it (I am still a WPF noob ;) )

Another solution is to move the `Popup` outside the `Ribbon` control, then it starts behaving as expected.

```
<Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <ribbon:Ribbon x:Name="Ribbon">
        <ribbon:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
            <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu SmallImageSource="Images\SmallIcon.png">
                <ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenuItem Header="Hello _Ribbon"
                                              x:Name="MenuItem1"
                                              ImageSource="Images\LargeIcon.png"/>
            </ribbon:RibbonApplicationMenu>
        </ribbon:Ribbon.ApplicationMenu>
        <ribbon:RibbonTab x:Name="HomeTab" 
                      Header="Home">
            <ribbon:RibbonGroup x:Name="Group1" 
                            Header="Group1">
                <ribbon:RibbonButton x:Name="Button1"
                                 LargeImageSource="Images\LargeIcon.png"
                                 Label="Button1"
                                 Click="Button1_Click"/>

                <Button Click="Button1_Click" Content="Open popup" />

            </ribbon:RibbonGroup>
        </ribbon:RibbonTab>
    </ribbon:Ribbon>
    <Popup PlacementTarget="{Binding ElementName=Button1}"
                   StaysOpen="False"
                   Name="p">
        <TextBlock Background="Green" Text="Popup Text" />
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```