# Popup not closing with 2 way binding to button

Tags: wpf, binding, popup

I have a custom control that is based around the functionality of a combobox.

Below, is the simplified template :

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication70.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="MainWindow"
        WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen">
    <StackPanel>
        <Grid>
            <ToggleButton  Name="PART_DropDownButton"
                           MinHeight="20"
                           ClickMode="Release">
                <Path x:Name="BtnArrow"
                      Height="4"
                      Width="8"
                      Stretch="Uniform"
                      Data="F1 M 301.14,-189.041L 311.57,-189.041L 306.355,-182.942L 301.14,-189.041 Z "
                      Margin="0,0,6,0"
                      Fill="Black"
                      HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
            </ToggleButton>
            <Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsChecked, Mode=TwoWay, ElementName=PART_DropDownButton}"
                   StaysOpen="False"
                   MaxHeight="400">
                <Ellipse Fill="Red"
                         Width="50"
                         Height="50" />
            </Popup>
        </Grid>
    </StackPanel>
</Window>
```

This seems to work, in that I can click the button, the popup opens, and then it closes when I click outside the popup.

However, I want the popup to open when the button is pressed, not released. But changing 'ClickMode' to Press stops the popup closing when you click outside the popup.

How can I solve this?

Comment: Have you seen this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2333905/wpf-popup-hiding-problem?

Comment: I don't seem to see a solution there, all the answers presented seem to just introduce other problems.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Managed to figure this out by reading the .net source code for ComboBox (didn't know about CaptureMode.SubTree, so also learnt something new :) ). Here is a userControl showing the answer in practice.

XAML

```
<UserControl x:Class="WpfApplication74.CustomDropdown"
         xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
         xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml">
<Grid>
    <ToggleButton  Name="PART_DropDownButton"
                   IsChecked="{Binding IsOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
                   MinHeight="20"
                   HorizontalContentAlignment="Right"
                   ClickMode="Press">
        <Path x:Name="BtnArrow"
              Height="4"
              Width="8"
              Stretch="Uniform"
              Data="F1 M 301.14,-189.041L 311.57,-189.041L 306.355,-182.942L 301.14,-189.041 Z "
              Margin="0,0,6,0"
              Fill="Black" />
    </ToggleButton>
    <Popup IsOpen="{Binding IsOpen, Mode=TwoWay, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType={x:Type UserControl}}}"
           StaysOpen="False"
           MaxHeight="400"
           Width="{Binding ActualWidth, ElementName=PART_DropDownButton}"
           Opened="OnPopupOpened"
           Name="PART_Popup">
        <Border BorderThickness="1"
                BorderBrush="Black"
                Background="#EEE"
                Padding="20">
            <StackPanel>
                <TextBox />
                <Slider />
                <TextBox />
                <Slider />
            </StackPanel>
        </Border>
    </Popup>
</Grid>
```

Code-behind

```
public partial class CustomDropdown : UserControl
{
    public bool IsOpen
    {
        get { return (bool)GetValue(IsOpenProperty); }
        set { SetValue(IsOpenProperty, value); }
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty IsOpenProperty =
        DependencyProperty.Register("IsOpen", typeof(bool), typeof(CustomDropdown), new PropertyMetadata(false));

    public CustomDropdown()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    void OnPopupOpened(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        Mouse.Capture(this, CaptureMode.SubTree);
    }

    protected override void OnMouseDown(MouseButtonEventArgs e)
    {
        base.OnMouseDown(e);

        if (Mouse.Captured == this && e.OriginalSource == this)
        {
            SetCurrentValue(CustomDropdown.IsOpenProperty, false);
            ReleaseMouseCapture();
        }

        e.Handled = true;
    }
}
```

Comment: thx very much. it was new for me too and helped me a lot. I call Mouse.Capture in the IsOpen dependency property changed event. (like combobox reference source https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#PresentationFramework/src/Framework/System/windows/Controls/ComboBox.cs,26d4d26579e03147,references). Otherwise i had problems opening the same popup from another element of the user control.

Comment: Nothing much changed in 8 years. Thank you for taking the ti e to answer your own question. It helped me.

Answer (score 0):

Try to manually set the property `IsOpen` of Popup in the events: Checked and Unchecked, and when the Popup is closed, reset `ToggleButton.IsChecked` to False.

Example:

`XAML`

```
<StackPanel>
    <Grid>
        <ToggleButton  Name="PART_DropDownButton"
                       Checked="PART_DropDownButton_Checked"
                       Unchecked="PART_DropDownButton_Unchecked">

            <Path x:Name="BtnArrow"
                  Height="4"
                  Width="8"
                  Stretch="Uniform"
                  Data="F1 M 301.14,-189.041L 311.57,-189.041L 306.355,-182.942L 301.14,-189.041 Z "
                  Margin="0,0,6,0"
                  Fill="Black"
                  HorizontalAlignment="Right" />
        </ToggleButton>

        <Popup Name="MyPopup"
               StaysOpen="False"
               Closed="MyPopup_Closed"
               MaxHeight="400">

            <Ellipse Fill="White"
                     Width="50"
                     Height="50" />
        </Popup>
    </Grid>
</StackPanel>
```

`Code-behind`

```
public partial class MainWindow : Window
{
    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    private void MyPopup_Closed(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (PART_DropDownButton != Mouse.DirectlyOver)
            PART_DropDownButton.IsChecked = false;
    }

    private void PART_DropDownButton_Checked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyPopup.IsOpen = true;
    }

    private void PART_DropDownButton_Unchecked(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MyPopup.IsOpen = false;
    }
}
```

Comment: Not sure what this is supposed to help with. The problem is that I want to set the ClickMode to "Press", so that the popup opens when the mouse is down, but doing so disables the usual 'Close popup when you click outside of it' behaviour